# httpUnit error in java

Tags: java, webclient

hello i am using httpUnit and i have the following error

> org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function attachEvent in object [object Image].
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3654)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3632)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3660)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3679)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3743)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2247)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2214)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:3143)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:2487)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:398)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3065)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:175)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateString(Context.java:1104)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.javascript.ScriptingEngineImpl.runScript(ScriptingEngineImpl.java:92)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.scripting.ScriptableDelegate.runScript(ScriptableDelegate.java:88)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.parsing.NekoDOMParser.runScript(NekoDOMParser.java:151)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.parsing.ScriptFilter.getTranslatedScript(ScriptFilter.java:150)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.parsing.ScriptFilter.endElement(ScriptFilter.java:131)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1136)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1038)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:329)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:2999)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:1991)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:895)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
>           at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.parsing.NekoHTMLParser.parse(NekoHTMLParser.java:48)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.HTMLPage.parse(HTMLPage.java:271)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebResponse.getReceivedPage(WebResponse.java:1301)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebResponse.getFrames(WebResponse.java:1285)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebResponse.getFrameRequests(WebResponse.java:1024)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.FrameHolder.updateFrames(FrameHolder.java:179)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateFrameContents(WebWindow.java:315)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebClient.updateFrameContents(WebClient.java:526)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateWindow(WebWindow.java:201)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getSubframeResponse(WebWindow.java:183)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResponse(WebWindow.java:158)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateWindow(WebWindow.java:199)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getSubframeResponse(WebWindow.java:183)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResponse(WebWindow.java:158)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResponse(WebWindow.java:125)
>           at com.meterware.httpunit.WebClient.getResponse(WebClient.java:96)
>           at websitereader.Main.main(Main.java:83)
>   Exception in thread "main" com.meterware.httpunit.ScriptException: Script '(function(){
>   var b,d,e,f;function g(a,c){if(a.removeEventListener){a.removeEventListener("load",c,false);a.removeEventListener("error",c,false)}else{a.detachEvent("onload",c);a.detachEvent("onerror",c)}}function h(a){f=(new Date).getTime();++d;a=a||window.event;var c=a.target||a.srcElement;g(c,h)}var i=document.getElementsByTagName("img");b=i.length;d=0;for(var j=0,k;j

and i am using netbeans and adding the jar rhino1_7R2( js, js14) and httpunit-1.7

how can i solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of your stack trace says:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function attachEvent in object [object Image]
```

Well, this could possibly mean that an object called `Image` doesn't have a function called `attachEvent` which you're calling somewhere. And since you didn't provide the relevant bit of source code, it's just a guess.

By the way, this line

```
(function(){ var b,d,e,f;function g(a,c)
```

scares me. I hope you aren't actually going to really leave those variables named like that.

Comment: this is my code                                                            WebConversation wc = new WebConversation();
    WebResponse   resp = wc.getResponse( "http://www.google.com" ); // read this page
    WebLink       link = resp.getLinkWith( "response" );                                // find the link
    link.click();                                                                       // follow it
    WebResponse   jdoc = wc.getCurrentPage();
     System.out.println("***********"+jdoc.getLinks());